# MySQL "UPDATE" doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have this query on my CMS but it doesn't work. I try to update the member's profile...

```
<?php
// INCLUDE FILES
include('config.cms.php');
include('php/connect_db.php');
// PREPARE STRINGS
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['full_name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
if (isset($_POST['avatar']))
{
    $avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
}
else
{
    $avatar = '';
}
$avatar_type = $_POST['avatar_type'];
$slogan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['slogan']);
$privacy = $_POST['privacy'];
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bio']);
// QUERY THE DB
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `full_name`='".$full_name."', `email`='".$email."', `avatar`='".$avatar."', `avatar_type`='".$avatar_type."', `user_slogan`='".$slogan."', `privacy`='".$privacy."', `location`='".$location."', `bio`='".$bio."' WHERE `id`='".$user_id."'");
// GET ERROR IF EXIST
mysql_error();
// REDIRECT AFTER COMPLETED
header('Location: profile.php?saved');
?>
```

Is there any error because I can't find anything!

Comment: I would love to POST `user_id="123'; DROP TABLE users; --"` to your application.

Comment: Save your query in a variable and then `echo` it. Update the OP with that. Also, just `mysql_error()` doesn't do anything - that function returns a string. So you need to use `echo mysql_error();` to actually see errors.

Comment: @Borealid The `user_id` is not fillable by user... It's a hidden input ;)

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux The user can post whatever they want, regardless of whether an input field is hidden (even if there is no input field at all).

Comment: @Borealid I added the `mysql_real_escape_string()` to it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ...");
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die();
}
```

See also:
http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

The [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) function doesn't make errors show up magically.

You must `echo mysql_error();` or the like to have it *do* anything - otherwise, you get the error but then throw it away.

Also, please learn from [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327) - you have not sanitized your user IDs, nor avatar types, nor privacy field. **ALL** - and I mean **ALL** - user input must be sanitized. I strongly recommend using PDO and parametrized queries instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. They are both safer and easier to understand.